# How to render sql result with node js

Tags: html, sql, node.js, express, templates

I am trying to display all users of my database using `node js`. 
This is my code :

```
app.get('/users', (req,res) => {
   var sql = "SELECT * FROM Users"
   con.query(sql, (err,result) => {
       if(err){
           console.log('SQL ERROR');
       }else{
          res.render('users.ejs', {user_list: result})
      }
   })
})
```

With the following code in user.ejs:

```
<%= user_list %>
```

This is what I see when I go to my `/users` page :

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

I would like to display the contents of these objects.
I tried to use javascript this way, unsuccessfully:

```
<script>console.log(<%= user_list%>)</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `res.render('users.ejs', {user_list: result[0]})`

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.